# How to create a table with alternate colspan with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table

I want to create a table that look like that:

```
|¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯|
|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
|¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯|
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

with angular, using ng-repeat.

I tried to do it with this html but it doesn't work.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
        <th>col4</th>
        <th>col5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <tr>
          <td>{{item.val1}}</td>
          <td>{{item.val2}}</td>
          <td>{{item.val3}}</td>
          <td>{{item.val4}}</td>
          <td>{{item.val5}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">QWERTY</td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: "doesn't work" is a no-no. You need to tell us what happened, or whether you got any error messages.

Comment: Look into `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` which allows you to accomplish what you're after.

Comment: yes, it works well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` when you can't accomplish what you're after by placing `ng-repeat` on a single element. Something like:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="item in items">
        <td>{{item.val1}}</td>
        <td>{{item.val2}}</td>
        <td>{{item.val3}}</td>
        <td>{{item.val4}}</td>
        <td>{{item.val5}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
        <td colspan="5">QWERTY</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```